# Get the issuer of a SamlSecurityToken

Tags: wif

I have a WIF RP, with multiple trusted issuers configured, e.g:

```
<trustedIssuers>
  <add thumbprint="..." name="Issuer1" />
  <add thumbprint="..." name="Issuer2" />
</trustedIssuers>
```

I'm trying to get hold of which particular issuer a token came from. I was hoping the [IssuerNameRegistry.GetIssuerName(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee747522.aspx) would do the trick, but it seems to return null unless the supplied token is a an X509SecurityToken.

In the `WSFederationAuthenticationModule`'s `SecurityTokenReceived` event I observe the following;

The received `SamlSecurityToken` exposes a `SamlAssertion` which has a private field `_issuerToken`, of type `X509SecurityToken`.

So, the information is there it seems, I'm just not able to get hold of it.

In short, how do I figure out which trusted issuer issued the token? Any help appreciated.

PS! I'm aware that the token has not yet been validated in the `SecurityTokenReceived` event. I would preferably get this information after the token has been validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Eugenio, you pointed me in the right direction. Turns out the issuer is included in the claim, in the [Claim.Issuer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claim.issuer.aspx), which makes perfect sense when you think about it — you might have claims from different issuers.

So with the example config:

```
<trustedIssuers>
  <add thumbprint="..." name="Issuer1" />
  <add thumbprint="..." name="Issuer2" />
</trustedIssuers>
```

The `Claim.Issuer` property returns "Issuer1" if the claim came from "Issuer1".

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, the `ClaimsPrincipal` has an `Issuer` property. That might be easier (look in the `Identity` property (don't have a machine with me right now and can't verify).

Comment: Thanks, this was very close! `Claim` has the `Issuer`property, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the other version with the single parameter (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee747522.aspx)?

It's an abstract method so you'd need to get the concrete version defined by whatever is in the web.config.