# Find out which federated partner issued token to WIF

Tags: asp.net, wif, adfs, federated-identity, ws-federation

I have an application that uses the Windows Identity Foundation to enable federated single-sign-on from multiple partners (let's call them Org1, Org2, Org3, etc). My WIF configuration, therefore, contains thumbprints of all the partners' certificates - the config looks like this (irrelevant parts omitted for brevity):

```
<system.identityModel>
<identityConfiguration>    
  <issuerNameRegistry type="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry">
    <trustedIssuers>
      <add name="Org1" thumbprint="...certificate1..." />
      <add name="Org2" thumbprint="...certificate2..." />
      <add name="Org3" thumbprint="...certificate3..." />
    </trustedIssuers>
  </issuerNameRegistry>
</identityConfiguration>
```

However, **I don't understand how to determine which of the certificates was actually used when an incoming token was validated**. That is, how do I know whether it was Org1, Org2 or Org3 that has sent me the token? I.e., in the following code:

```
        var authModule = FederatedAuthentication.WSFederationAuthenticationModule;
        var request = new HttpRequestWrapper(Request);

        if (authModule.CanReadSignInResponse(request, true))
        {
            var principal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
            var message = authModule.GetSignInResponseMessage(request);
            var token = authModule.GetSecurityToken(request) as SamlSecurityToken;
            //???
        }
```

... How can I use the `principal`/`message`/`token` variables (or perhaps some other method entirely) to determine whether it was Org1, Org2 or Org3 that has sent me the token? I know about `token.Assertion.Issuer`, but this seems to come straight from the token, so it seems like e.g. Org1 can issue a token listing Org2 as the issuer, thus resulting in an impersonation attack. Is there a way to identify the issuing organization **securely**, based on which certificate was used for token validation?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find 2 solutions:

METHOD 1:

Create a custom `IssuerNameRegistry` that derives from `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry`, and set it as your name registry (e.g. `<issuerNameRegistry type="MyNamespace.MyConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry, My.Assembly.Name">`).

In your custom registry, override the `GetIssuerName` overload that takes both a token and a string (which is the token's issuer **according to the token itself**).

In this override, call the base `GetIssuerName` method, and you will get back the `name` property of the `<add thumbprint="..." name="...">` statement for the certificate **that was actually used to verify the token signature**.

At this point, you have all the information you need (who the token claims to be, and who it is actually from). Compare the two, and return `null` if the token is impersonated (this will cause WIF to reject the token), or return what you got from the base method otherwise.

If your `name` property in `<add>` statements is always the intended token issuer URL, then all this becomes very easy:

```
class ValidatingConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry : ConfigurationBasedIssuerNameRegistry
{
    public override string GetIssuerName(SecurityToken securityToken, string requestedIssuerName)
    {
        var configuredName = base.GetIssuerName(securityToken, requestedIssuerName);
        return (configuredName == requestedIssuerName) ? configuredName : null;
    }
}
```

METHOD 2:

As stated in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17043658/get-the-issuer-of-a-samlsecuritytoken), you can get to the `Claims` on `Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal`, and each `Claim` has an `Issuer` property. It turns out that this property will always be set to the `name` property in the `<add thumbprint="..." name="...">` statement for the certificate that was **actually used** to verify the token signature.

This is a bit inconvenient - if you're processing a WS-Federation sign-in response, there's no way of knowing where **this particular response's** token came from - you're looking at the current Identity where the claims could potentially come from multiple sources. But I think in most realistic scenarios this should be sufficient.